# Why is movement constructor invoked twice while std::emplace_back is called only once?

Tags: c++, move, move-semantics

I understand that `std::emplace_back` uses placement-new to construct the element in-place at the location provided by the container.

Why is movement constructor invoked twice while `std::emplace_back` is called only once?

Here is the related code(check https://godbolt.org/z/-NXzNY):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct President
{
    std::string name;
    std::string country;
    int year;

    President(std::string p_name, std::string p_country, int p_year)
        : name(std::move(p_name)), country(std::move(p_country)), year(p_year)
    {
        std::cout << "I am being constructed.\n";
    }
    President(President&& other)
        : name(std::move(other.name)), country(std::move(other.country)), year(other.year)
    {
        std::cout << "I am being moved.\n";
    }
    President& operator=(const President& other) = default;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<President> elections;
    std::cout << "emplace_back:\n";
    elections.emplace_back("Nelson Mandela", "South Africa", 1994);

    President pst("Franklin", "the USA", 1936);

    std::cout << "=====================" << std::endl;
    elections.emplace_back(std::move(pst));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two objects; Putting the second to the vector causes a vector resize, memory reallocation, hence the movement requirement. In addition to construction-in-place that `emplace_back` does, that's another point of the move construction: To avoid expensive copies when `std::vector` resizes.

When adding this line to your code:

```
elections.reserve(2);
```

Then you have only one movement.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. One more question, why does not `std::vector<President> elections(3);` compile whereas `std::vector<int> numVec(5);` is ok?

Comment: Because your class does not have a default constructor (that is, one that can be called without arguments).

Comment: @John `President` has a user-defined constructor, so the default constructor doesn't get generated by the compiler.  Since it doesn't have a default constructor, `std::vector`'s constructor that accepts a size cannot default-construct 3 `President` elements.  `std::vector`'s constructor constructs a vector with an initial _size_ (the number of objects it logically holds).  `reserve` affects the vector's _capacity_ (the number of elements it can hold before needing to allocate new storage).

Comment: @MilesBudnek & Michael Chourdakis Thanks to both of you. If I understand you correctly, I can draw two conclusions:              1: `std::vector(ssize_t)` **could only invoke** the default constructor or user defined constructor whose signature is `T()`.                  2: It's better to use `vector<T>::reserve` to affect the vector's capacity. Am I right?

Comment: @John Right, `std::vector(std::size_t)` (and `std::vector::resize`) default-constructs N objects.  `std::vector::reserve` pre-allocates enough uninitialized storage to hold N objects, but does not create any objects in that space until you add them to the vector using `push_back`, `emplace_back`, `insert`, etc.

Comment: @MilesBudnek & Michael Chourdakis I had been confused for a long time. I fully understand it now with your help. I am very grateful to both of you.